# Creating Excel 2010 Instance in Access 2010

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Crazy thing here, but I am trying to initialize an Excel 2010 instance from Access 2010. (Something I've done in 07 / 03 many times before). Whether I use late or early binding I get an error message on the `Set` line stating that

`Excel has stopped working`

`A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program.`

Anyone have any ideas?

Here's my binding code in case it helps:

```
'late binding
Dim xlApp As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Early Binding (of course I have my reference set to Microsoft Excel Object Library
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
```

Oh yes, I am on Win7 as well.

**Update**

I tested a bit by trying to initialize a Word and Access instance and it worked without fail. Furthermore, I tried initialize the XL on a remote desktop connection and got the same error.

This is leading me away from a full XL re-install, as the issue is related to XL on two different machines at this point, but no other application.

**Update2**

This error seems to be incurring on all 2010 XL Win7 installs at my office.

This is the Event Log description of the error:

```
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 14.0.6126.5003, time stamp: 0x505b0834
Faulting module name: mso.dll, version: 14.0.6123.5001, time stamp: 0x4fe1743b
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000d44e9
Faulting process id: 0x1ac0
Faulting application start time: 0x01cdda417700ac49
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\office14\mso.dll
Report Id: b51c3820-4634-11e2-b879-e4115b51637e
```

Comment: I guess you have installed all updates and run a repair on your Excel Application? Are you sure you have not got any copies running in task manager? Have you compacted & repaired and decompiled?

Comment: @Remou -> Yes, thanks. I did all that good stuff...  well, all except update / repair XL. I don't have those privileges.

Comment: I am afraid you are going to have to try a repair of the Excel install as a step in troubleshooting. I am using Excel 2010 & Access 2010 on a Windows 7 machine and it works fine.

Comment: @Remou -> please see my edited post, does this shed any light for you?

Comment: What does it say about it in the Event Log?

Comment: @JamesSnell -> Thanks for this comment. I've edited my post with what the Event Log says.

Comment: Might be worth a try: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/diagnose-and-repair-crashing-office-programs-by-using-office-diagnostics-HA001234076.aspx